# SQL Compare rows of a table with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table T1

| Id | Col1 | Col2 | IsActive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T1 | v1 | 1 |
| 2 | T2 | v2 | 0 |

Now received the following data and it need to be inserted into the above table.

```
|  Col1  |  Col2  |  
|--------|--------|
|   T1   |   v1   |
|   T2   |   v2   |
|   T3   |   v3   |
```

As this data contains some duplicated values, it need to be inserted based on IsActive Column value. For row with IsActive 1, need to insert with IsActive 2 and for row with IsActive 0, need to insert with IsActive 1 like below, the unique data need to be inserted with IsActive 1 and that is not a problem right now

| Id | Col1 | Col2 | IsActive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T1 | v1 | 1 |
| 2 | T2 | v2 | 0 |
| 3 | T1 | v1 | 2 |
| 4 | T2 | v2 | 1 |
| 5 | T3 | v3 | 1 |

I have created a Temp table #Temp and inserted common rows in new incoming data and data from existing table like below:

**#Temp**

| Col1 | Col2 | IsActive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | v1 | 1 |
| T2 | v2 | 0 |
| T1 | v1 | NULL |
| T2 | v2 | NULL |

Using Group By I can able to select duplicate rows but I need to insert based on IsActive value, so I stuck here.

```
insert into T1
select Col1, Col2, '1' from #Temp
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
HAVING COUNT(Col1) > 1
```

I need help on this above part, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this:
    
-- create temp table with values to be inserted
INSERT INTO #ToInsert
    ([Col1], [Col2])
VALUES
    ('T1', 'v1'),
    ('T2', 'v2'),
    ('T3', 'v3')

-- join each value of the temp table to the original table. if
-- value exists increment its `IsActive` by 1, otherwise set it to 1
INSERT INTO t (Col1, Col2, IsActive)
SELECT i.Col1, i.Col2, COALESCE(t.IsActive + 1, 1) AS IsActive
FROM #ToInsert i
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT Col1, Col2, max(IsActive) as IsActive
   FROM t 
   GROUP BY Col1, Col2
) t ON i.Col1 = t.Col1 AND i.Col2 = t.Col2
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8c429/1)

Comment: What if the next iteration has ('T1','v1') again? Do you need to insert ('T1','v1',3)? If so, then instead of `LEFT JOIN` to `t` itself, you'd want to join to `(SELECT Col1, Col2, max(IsActive FROM t GROUP BY Col1, Col2) AS t`